# How to change a background image of a qml button while press and release

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.4

I need to change the background image of a `Button` while it is pressed.
If I have a background image on the `Button` before it is pressed, I need to change that background image, when the `Button` is pressed, and then set it back to the original background image when the `Button` is released.

Here is my current code :

```
property bool bImgChange: true

Button {
    id: bu
    x: 121
    y: 40
    iconSource: "q.png"
    activeFocusOnPress: false
    opacity: 1
    checkable: true
    checked: true
    Layout.minimumWidth: 100
    Layout.minimumHeight: 100

    onClicked: {
        if ( bImgChange == true )
        {
            bu.iconSource = "index.png"
            bImgChange = false
        }
        else
        {
            bu.iconSource = "q.png"
            bImgChange = true
        }
    }
}
```

The above code only sets the background image while the `Button` is clicked whereas I need to change the background image on presses and releases.

Answer (score 5):

`Button` has a property `pressed` which can be used like this:

```
Item {
    Image { source: btn.pressed? "image1.png" : "image2.png"; ...}
    Button { id: btn; ... }
}
```

or, if you want to change the `iconSource` of the `Button`, you can try something like this:

```
Button {
    iconSource: pressed? "image1.png" : "image2.png"
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks man, its really help me and i can't  have enough reputation to marks upwards

Comment: It won't work, you need to put it in an event I think

Comment: Yes you need to put it in onButtonPressed event